# How do i write this methods with streams and lambdas?

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

We started with streams and lambdas today in programming class and i have to do an exercise.

The first task was to write a method that calculates the average of even numbers in a list. I have written this code but obviously i did not make use of streams.

```
public static double average(List<Integer> list) {

    double sum = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for (Integer integer : list) {
        if (integer % 2 == 0) {
            i++;
            sum += integer;
        }
    }
    return (sum / i);
}
```

EDIT Solution:

```
int sum = list.stream().filter(integer -> integer % 2 == 0).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
long count = list.stream().filter(integer -> integer % 2 == 0).count();
```

The second task was to write a method that selects all strings that start with "a" (case insensitive) or have 3 characters and change it to upper case.
My code:

```
public static List<String> upperCase(List<String> list) {

    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        if(list.get(i).length() == 3 || Character.toString(list.get(i).charAt(0)).equalsIgnoreCase("a")){
            list.set(i, list.get(i).toUpperCase());
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

EDIT: Solution:

```
public static List<String> upperCase(List<String> list) {


    List<String> newListOfStrings = list.stream().map(string -> string.length() == 3 ||
            Character.toString(string.charAt(0)).equalsIgnoreCase("a") ? string.toUpperCase() : string).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return newListOfStrings;
```

The last task was to return the list but add "g" to even numbers and "u" to odd numbers.
My code:

```
public static String getString(List<Integer> list){
    String s = "";
    for(Integer integer : list){
        if(integer % 2 == 0){
            s += integer.toString() + "g,";}
        else {
            s += integer.toString()+ "u,";
        }

    }
    return s.substring(0, s.length()-1);
}
```

EDIT: Solution:

```
public static String getString (List < Integer > list) {

    String result = list.stream()
            .map(integer -> integer % 2 == 0 ?
                    String.format("%d%s", integer, "g") : String.format("%d%s", integer, "u"))
            .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
    return result;
```

I would really appreciate if someone could tell me how the first task would look like with streams. I will try the two others on my own.

Kind regards

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i think i have to start like this: "list.stream().forEach ... my problem is that i don't know how to implement the if condition in the stream.

Comment: If condition in the stream is done using `filter()`. Did you **read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html), to see what methods are available to you? --- Question down-voted because it "does not show any research effort" *(quoting tooltip of down-vote button)*.

Comment: you are right, i did not read the documentation. it is very overwhelming for me. i have the following code now: `OptionalDouble sum = list.stream().filter(integer -> integer % 2 == 0).mapToDouble(Integer::intValue).average();` is there a better way of implementing it? i want to get rid of the OptionalDouble because the task is to return a normal double

Comment: Please never add more infos in comments, always update your question instead.

Comment: You can post your solution as an answer, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The first task was to write a method that calculates the average of even numbers in a list.

The point is to change the boxed `Stream<Integer` to `IntStream` which provides method for aggregating operation such as sum, average, min, max etc.

```
double average = list.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).average().getAsDouble;
```

Remember, the `NoSuchElementException` might be thrown if no average is present in `OptionalDouble`.

> The second task was to write a method that selects all strings that start with "a" (case insensitive) or have 3 characters and change it to upper case.

You `forEach` method at the end of the stream is a terminal operation that requires a `Consumer`, which consumes the method. Although you call `toUpperCase`, it doesn't change the original collection and the result is thrown (unless you print it out).

You wan to perform the mapping of the qualified strings using method `map`. As long as you want only to modify these values and keep the remaining at the same time, you cannot use `filter` as long as it can modify the number of items streamed. Do this:

```
List<String> newListOfStrings = listOfStrings.stream()
    .map(string -> string.length() == 3 || string.startsWith("a") ? 
                   string.toUpperCase() : string)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Notice I have used `startsWith` method that is easier to use. Your usage of `charAt`  is not incorrect, though.

> The last task was to return the list but add "g" to even numbers and "u" to odd numbers.

Not the best, but fairly acceptable solution is again using mapping method `map` and finally `Collectors.joining(",")` that joins the items to a string with a delimiter. Therefore you don't need to bother with `,` characters.

```
String result = list.stream()
    .map(integer -> integer % 2 == 0 ? integer + "g" : integer + "u")
    .collect(Collectors.joining(","));

// I find String.format better than using +
String result = list.stream()
        .map(integer -> integer % 2 == 0 ?
            String.format("%d%s", integer, "g") : String.format("%d%s", integer, "u"))
        .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

However, if I were to implement the 3rd one, I would use simple for-each iteration and `StringBuilder` that is suitable for the string concatenation:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (Integer integer: list) {
    sb.append(integer);
    if (integer % 2 == 0) {
        sb.append("g,");
    } else {
        sb.append("u,");
    }
}
String result = sb.toString().substring(0, sb.length() - 1);
```

... or using a new collection with `String.join` method ...

```
List<String> newList = new ArrayList<>();
for (Integer integer: list) {
    String toAdd = integer % 2 == 0 ? 
        String.format("%d%s", integer, "g") : 
        String.format("%d%s", integer, "u");
    newList.add(toAdd);
}
String result = String.join(",", newList);
```

Comment: How about a [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) (rather than a `StringBuilder`) for the last one?

Comment: @OleV.V.: I was thinking about that, but you have to concatenate an integer with either `"g"` or `"u"` inside the loop (using `String.format`) since calling `StringJoiner::add` places a new delimiter. Could you provide an example?

Comment: Being so fond of streams I’d just do `list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::valueOf).mapToObj(i -> i % 2 == 0 ? i + "g" : i + "u").collect(Collectors.joining(","))`. Feel free to disapprove. :-)

Comment: `mapToInt` is not needed and you can map directly to string (the input list is `List<Integer>`, so: `list.stream().map(i -> i % 2 == 0 ? i + "g" : i + "u").collect(Collectors.joining(","))`. The `+` handles the conversion. Moreover, I wanted to avoid the string concatenation using `+` at the first case. Am I missing something?

Comment: Matter of taste. I like the concatenation. Maybe if we understood better why the OP wants that output, we’d have a better idea whether it’s good or bad. PS I don’t like putting the `int` first in the concatenation, though. I might do `"" + i + "g"` or even `String.valueOf(i) + 'g'`.

Comment: thank you very much @Nikolas
i had struggle with the last one for two hours now!

I'm using `charAt(0)).equalsIgnoreCase("a")` because the "a" needs to be case insensitive and i could not figure out how to implement it with `startsWith()`

Comment: For case-insensitive "start-with" use `string.toLowerString().startsWith("a")`. The original `string` won't be changed since strings are immutable as long as you don't assign it back to `string`..